# Run jQuery click function ONCE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting this click function to run **one single time** per turnRound() call. So I put it in an if-statement that should get broken after one execution, due to the humanMoved variable being true. But clicking on an element with the "square" class still calls the click function. `turnRound()` is called only once as well. I'm thinking this might be a variable scope problem with humanMoved, or I just don't understand `.click()`

```
function turnRound(c){
    humanMoved = false;
    if (c == "X" && humanMoved == false) {
        $(".square").click(function(){
            $(this).text(c);
            humanMoved = true;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Use `one('click', fn);`

Comment: humanMoved is set to false each time turnRound() is called.

Comment: What Dave said. You just need to move your humanMoved variable outside of the turnRound function. Otherwise it just reverts back to false on every click

Comment: Also, the if statement should be inside the click callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the following code:

```
$(".square").click(function(){
  $(this).text(c);
  humanMoved = true;
});
```

Replace it with either [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one):

```
$(".square").one("click", function(){
  $(this).text(c);
  humanMoved = true;
});
```

Or, you can remove the `click` event by using [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$(".square").click(function(){
  $(this).text(c);
  humanMoved = true;
  $(this).off("click");
});
```